# Why vite.js doesn't work when I use npm run dev

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, node-modules, vite

I create a react app with Vite, I go to the directory with `cd xxxxx`, I run `npm install`, then I follow `npm run dev`
Please help me, I dont want to use `Create-react-app` is to slow.
I have been searchin in blogs and nothing works, i have updated node.js, deprecated vite, deleted vite cache, uninstalled node, uninstalled VScode

```
X [ERROR] [plugin vite:dep-pre-bundle] Detected inconsistent metadata for the path "node_modules/react/index.js" when it was imported here:

    node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:16:20:
      16 │ var React = require('react');
         ╵                     ~~~~~~~

  The original metadata for that path comes from when it was imported here:

    dep:react:1:23:
      1 │ export default require("./node_modules/react/index.js");
        ╵                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  The difference in metadata is displayed below:
  
   {
  -  "pluginName": null,
  +  "pluginName": "vite:dep-pre-bundle",
   }

  This is a bug in the "vite:dep-pre-bundle" plugin. Plugins provide metadata for a given path in an
  "onResolve" callback. All metadata provided for the same path must be consistent to ensure
  deterministic builds. Due to parallelism, one set of provided metadata will be randomly chosen for
  a given path, so providing inconsistent metadata for the same path can cause non-determinism.

X [ERROR] [plugin vite:dep-pre-bundle] Detected inconsistent metadata for the path "node_modules/react/index.js" when it was imported here:

    node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16:20:
      16 │ var React = require('react');
         ╵                     ~~~~~~~

  The original metadata for that path comes from when it was imported here:

    dep:react:1:23:
      1 │ export default require("./node_modules/react/index.js");
        ╵                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  The difference in metadata is displayed below:

   {
  -  "pluginName": null,
  +  "pluginName": "vite:dep-pre-bundle",
   }

  This is a bug in the "vite:dep-pre-bundle" plugin. Plugins provide metadata for a given path in an
  "onResolve" callback. All metadata provided for the same path must be consistent to ensure
  deterministic builds. Due to parallelism, one set of provided metadata will be randomly chosen for
  a given path, so providing inconsistent metadata for the same path can cause non-determinism.
```

```
12:08:07 a. m. [vite] error while updating dependencies:
Error: Build failed with 2 errors:
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16:20: ERROR: [plugin: vite:dep-pre-bundle] Detected inconsistent metadata for the path "node_modules/react/index.js" when it was imported here:
node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:16:20: ERROR: [plugin: vite:dep-pre-bundle] Detected inconsistent metadata for the path "node_modules/react/index.js" when it was imported here:
    at failureErrorWithLog (C:\Users\feedm\Desktop\front\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1603:15)
    at C:\Users\feedm\Desktop\front\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1249:28
    at runOnEndCallbacks (C:\Users\feedm\Desktop\front\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1034:63)
    at buildResponseToResult (C:\Users\feedm\Desktop\front\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1247:7)
    at C:\Users\feedm\Desktop\front\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1356:14
    at C:\Users\feedm\Desktop\front\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:666:9
    at handleIncomingPacket (C:\Users\feedm\Desktop\front\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:763:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (C:\Users\feedm\Desktop\front\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:632:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
```

Answer (score 6):

This was caused by [`esbuild#2177`](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/2177#issuecomment-1096200814) (on which Vite depends), which was just recently reverted in `esbuild` version 0.14.36.

This issue should no longer occur with Vite, but you'll have to delete any lockfiles (i.e., `package-lock.json`, `yarn.lock`, etc.) and `node_modules/`, and re-install dependencies, as [reported here](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/7683#issuecomment-1096310011).

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when I installed new package vie-owl-carousel.

```
 yarn add vue-owl-carousel
```

When I removed it by yarn

```
 yarn remove vue-owl-carousel
```

This error showed to me.

```
12:08:07 a. m. [vite] error while updating dependencies:
Error: Build failed with 2 errors:...
```

I installed it again and app ran successfully. Then I removed it by npm uninstall  and the problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Github issue open for this.  For now I was able to resolve by locking the package.json version of Vite to "vite": "~2.7.1"

https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/7683

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, and I was using vuejs3 and vite 4.x, to solve this problem I had to run `npm outdated` to see if there were any updates, and after I I had to reinstall only the esbuild by doing npm i esbuild https://www.npmjs.com/package/esbuild?activeTab=explore